How to fix "failed to install or launch the test runner" without using Rosetta?
My project is a native iOS application. I'm using CircleCI for CI/CD and I get an error when running unit tests using a simulator unless I'm using Rosetta. The CircleCI uses Apple Silicon to run my jobs.
This is what my config.yml file looks like.
version: 2.1

# setup: true

orbs:
  macos: circleci/macos@2.4.1
  ruby: circleci/ruby@2.1.2

parameters:
  application-nonprod-context:
    description: Context containing credentials for nonprod
    type: string
    default: application-nonprod-context-default-value

executors:
  my-executor:
    macos:
      xcode: "15.3.0"
      resource_class: macos.m1.large.gen1

commands:
  setup:
    description: Setup common to all jobs
    steps:
      - checkout
      - ruby/install-deps
jobs:
  run-tests:
    executor: my-executor
    steps:
      - setup
      - macos/install-rosetta
      - macos/preboot-simulator:
          device: iPhone 15 Pro
          version: "17.4"
      - run:
          name: Run unit tests using Fastlane
          command: bundle exec fastlane tests
workflows:
  code-changed: 
    jobs:
      - run-tests:
          context: << pipeline.parameters.application-nonprod-context >>
          filters:
            branches:
              only: /.*/

My Fastfile
# This file contains the fastlane.tools configuration
# You can find the documentation at https://docs.fastlane.tools
#
# For a list of all available actions, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
#
# For a list of all available plugins, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/available-plugins
#

# Uncomment the line if you want fastlane to automatically update itself
# update_fastlane

default_platform :ios

platform :ios do

  before_all do
    setup_circle_ci
  end

  desc "Run unit tests using scheme UnitTests"
  lane :tests do
    run_tests(workspace: "MyProject.xcworkspace",
    devices: ["iPhone 15 Pro (17.4)"],
    scheme: "UnitTests",
    clean: true,
    parallel_testing: false,
    configuration: "Debug",
    derived_data_path: ".Build")
  end

end

If I don't use Rosetta I see the following error in CircleCI.
Testing failed:
        Simulator device failed to launch com.mycompany.myapp.debug.
        MyApp encountered an error (Failed to install or launch the test runner. (Underlying Error: Simulator device failed to launch com.mycompany.myapp.debug. No such process. (Underlying Error: Application launch for 'com.mycompany.myapp.debug' did not return a process handle nor launch error. No such process)))

Anyone using simulators without rosetta in CircleCI + Apple silicon and has no problem doing so?
